# JScript Regex - extract 10-digit VAT number with seperators procedeed by a substring

Tags: regex, jscript

I need to extract VAT number that consists of 10 digits seperated by a dash, space or not seperated and procedeed by substring 'VAT'. VAT number never starts start with zero and is always followed by a space.

```
reg = new RegExp('[\d -]{10}\\s','ig');
str = ('sdfgzdfvzdfv/9/2020 VAT Invoice 16-09-2020 Citsxc zzzzw34  224- Iscvcge date 16.09.2020 VAT Terms 34 of payment:  123-456-78-90 *')
expected result: '123-456-78-90'
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try `reg = /\b[1-9](?:[\s-]?\d){9}(?=\s*VAT\b)/gi`

Comment: Thank you. I didn't work (e.g. 'VAT' substring proceeds the number) so I've changed it a bit - "new RegExp('VAT.*?[1-9](?:[\s-]?\\d){9}(?=\\s)','gi')" but now get "VAT Invoice 16-09-2020 Citsxc zzzzw34  224- Iscvcge date 16.09.2020 VAT Terms 34 of payment:  123-456-78-90" instead of number only. Any hint how to fix it?

Comment: Aha, so you can match with `RegExp("\\bVAT.*?\\b([1-9](?:[\\s-]?\\d){9})(?!\\S)", "i")` and then use `reg.exec(str)[1]`. Or, after running `exec`, use `RegExp.$1` to access the value.

Comment: I can't get it right with your suggestion thus use two expression RegExp('VAT.*?[1-9](?:[\s-]?\\d){9}(?=\\s)','gi') and RegExp('[1-9](?:[\s-]?\\d){9}','gi'). If you know how to make it work in one, I'd be thankful.

Comment: How can I test the code? Where can I run it? Is there any online IDE for  JScript?

Comment: var Reg  = RegExp('VAT.*?[1-9](?:[\s-]?\\d){9}(?=\\s)','gi')
var Reg2  = RegExp('[1-9](?:[\s-]?\\d){9}','gi')
text=('sdfgzdfvzdfv/9/2020 VAT Invoice 16-09-2020 Citsxc zzzzw34  224- Iscvcge date 16.09.2020 VAT Terms 34 of payment123-456-78-90 (?=\\s)*')
text = tekst.match(Reg).toString().match(Reg2).toString()
new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell').Popup(text)

Comment: var Reg  = RegExp('VAT.*?[1-9](?:[\s-]?\\d){9}(?=\\s)','gi')
var Reg2  = RegExp('[1-9](?:[\s-]?\\d){9}','gi')
text=('sdfgzdfvzdfv/9/2020 VAT Invoice 16-09-2020 Citsxc zzzzw34  224- Iscvcge date 16.09.2020 VAT Terms 34 of payment123-456-78-90 (?=\\s)*')
text = text.match(Reg).toString().match(Reg2).toString()
WScript.Echo(text)

Comment: Save one of the above code in .js extension file and run. First one requires ActiveX to be turned on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```js
var rx  = RegExp('VAT.*?([1-9](?:[\\s-]?\\d){9})(?!\\S)','i');
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WcYKUS/1). Details:

- `VAT` - a `VAT` substring
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `([1-9](?:[\s-]?\d){9})` - Group 1:

  - `[1-9]`  - a non-zero digit
  - `(?:[\s-]?\d){9}` - 9 occurrences of a whitespace or hyphen and then a digit
- `(?!\S)` - a right-hand whitespace boundary.

JScript code demo:

```js
var rx  = RegExp('VAT.*?([1-9](?:[\s-]?\\d){9})(?!\\S)','i');
var string=('sdfgzdfvzdfv/9/2020 VAT Invoice 16-09-2020 Citsxc zzzzw34 224- Iscvcge date 16.09.2020 VAT Terms 34 of payment123-456-78-90 ');
var m = string.match(rx);
if (m) {
  WScript.Echo(m[1]);
} else {
  WScript.Echo("No match!");
}
```

Output: `123-456-78-90`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Wiktor. Works beautifully! Would you thought please explain the magic behind it - I see the regex returns an array ot two results "VAT Invoice 16-09-2020 Citsxc zzzzw34 224- Iscvcge date 16.09.2020 VAT Terms 34 of payment123-456-78-90" and "123-456-78-90". (?!\\S) does that?

Comment: @PrzemyslawWojda `match` returns the whole match and all captured substrings if the `g` flag is not specified. `(?!\S)` is a right-hand whitespace boundary (matches a location that is immediately followed with whitespace, or is the end of a string).